# How to sso login with auth0 as idp without entering credential by user?

Tags: single-sign-on, auth0, onelogin, service-provider, idp

I have onelogin implemented in my project for sso login.I get user session form an api(one login) through that session user does not have to input email and password to authenticate himself, he can directly access service provider. I want to replace this with auth0 sso, but i dont know how replace this functionality, As far i have searched the web, auth0 does not have such api to login user with session, is there any way around this? or there is any api which i am missing through which i can login user without him entering email and password or any credential, so he can directly access the service provider?

I did not find any solution till now for this like to like replacement with auth0